# sorting while or after merging hashes, in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a hash thats looks like

```
myhash =   [{"project 1"=>{"09 Apr 12, Mon"=>"2.75"}}, {"project 1"=>{"11 Apr 12,
Wed"=>"3.200000047683716"}}, {"project 1"=>{"25 Apr 12, Wed"=>"0.5099999904632568"}},   
{"project 1"=>{"31 May 12, Thu"=>"1"}}, {"project 1"=>{"01 Jun 12, Fri"=>"1"}}, {"project  
2"=>  {"01 Jun 12, Fri"=>"0"}}, {"project 1"=>{"04 Jun 12, Mon"=>"0.25"}}]
```

I want to merge internal hashes based on their keys. such that keys are not duplicated

I tried,

```
myhash.inject{|memo, el| memo.merge( el ){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v.merge(new_v)}}
```

which is giving correct results

```
=>{"project 2"=>{"01 Jun 12, Fri"=>"0"}, "project 1"=>{"01 Jun 12, Fri"=>"1", "09 Apr 
12, Mon"=>"2.75", "11 Apr 12, Wed"=>"3.200000047683716", "31 May 12, Thu"=>"1", "25 Apr  
12, Wed"=>"0.5099999904632568", "04 Jun 12, Mon"=>"0.25"}}
```

but the order is lost. how to sort above hash on the basis of dates that are keys inside the hashes.

or at the time of merging itself order is maintained.

I am using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: How about converting them into some sort of Date object?

Comment: looks like thats the only options available with me. not sure though. there can be some better way

Comment: You've got a hash of hashes here. Is it the inner hashes that need sorting by date order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Note that I've parsed the dates in order to sort them. It should be trivial to get them back to your original format. `merged` is the merged unordered hash you provided.

```
merged.map{|k,v| { k => v.sort_by{|d,f| Date.strptime(d.split(',')[0],"%d %b %y").to_s   } } }
```

You might want to think about using Date objects and an array rather than a hash, which (in 1.8.7 at least) is unordered.

Comment: thnx. i would prefer hash because i need to send this data to client in json where i can convert it back to hash, for quick accessing

Comment: can dates be removed from the sorted output?

Comment: You can remove them with the filter method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-select